# What causes the upper limit on wavelength in optical fiber?

Tags: electromagnetism, laser, fiber-optics, waveguide

It's well known that a most given waveguide modes have a cutoff wavelength above which the mode is no longer supported. At low wavelengths, more modes are supported. But what happens at high wavelengths, and specifically in fiber optics? In a coaxial wire, the TEM00 mode is supported to DC, but in a hollow waveguide, it's not. As far as I can tell, it seems like the fundamental LP01 mode in a fiber does not have a cutoff wavelength.

Is this correct? If so, what causes the upper limit on fibers? All the fibers I see, e.g. from [Thorlabs](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=3125) or [Newport](https://www.newport.com/f/standard-polarization-maintaining-fibers) have upper limits on their wavelengths. What limits this? Is it something fundamental like a a cutoff frequency, or something more mundane, like loss in the glass / cladding? It's a bit hard to see why loss in the glass would limit it since larger wavelengths typically transmit through materials better. Eventually it seems that the mode would leak into the cladding, but it doesn't seem that this is likely the limit here considering how much the upper cutoff varies.

On a similar level, is there a lower limit to the core size of a single mode fiber? Since lower sizes have lower cutoff frequencies, if there's no cutoff frequency for the fundamental mode, it would seem that a good approach would be to make a single very small core fiber which could be single mode for near all relevant wavelengths.

Comment: Most likely the upper limit on wavelength has to do with the attenuation constant which is inversely proportional to wavelength: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant#Attenuation_constant

Comment: I think you have this backwards, if the attenuation constant is inversely proportional to the wavelength, longer wavelengths can go farther and be attenuated the same, so this would suggest better performance at long wavelengths. (Although it's not clear to me that this is true for optical fibers, wiki only lists this for copper, and it's due to the skin effect, which doesn't seem very comparable.)

Comment: Yeah,you're absolutely right. My mind was messed up there!